# How to subtract pixels from an elements current position using only JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Without using jQuery, is there a way to get an element's current position and add/subtract from it? Let's say an element has this CSS

```
position: relative;
top: 400px;
/*400px away from the top*/
```

Can JavaScript get the amount of pixels from "top" and subtract from it? I know that I can directly edit the top property with document.getElementById("element").style.top , but I want to get the value itself first, then subtract a number of pixels from that value, and then put the new value as the position. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to get the ***computedStyle*** of the element `let rect = getComputedStyle('el')`, assign this to a variable then you can use the ***top*** position to get amount set in your class => `rect.top` will give you the top position.

```js
const cont = document.querySelector('.cont')

function getTopPos(el){
  // get the computed style of element
  // get the top position using .top
  // split at px and get the first index which will be the number
  // subtract it by desired amount and concatenate px measurement back to the value
  let was = getComputedStyle(el).top;
  el.style.top = `${getComputedStyle(el).top.split('px')[0] - 300}px`
  console.log(`top position is now: ${getComputedStyle(el).top.split('px')[0]}px, was: ${was}`)
}

getTopPos(cont)
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cont {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  top: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">Was 400 pixels from top, now 100 pixels from top</div>
```

Comment: This is also a valid answer, it works well. May I ask why you used querySelector instead of getElementById?

Comment: No particular reason really. I tend to use classes  rather than ID's there is no mystical reasoning behind the querying use there. They would both do the same thing honestly, `querySelector` simply returns the first iteration of a selector it finds in the dom.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? Get the position from the top of the viewport, then subtract a value and return the new "offset from top value":

```js
const offsetValue = 49

const findNewPosition = (offset) => {

  const element = document.querySelector('#elementId').getBoundingClientRect().top
  return element - offset
}

findNewPosition(offsetValue)
```

Comment: Sort of, but this returns a non-exact, decimal value. I think I found a method that works exactly, so I'll post that. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works (it did for my case):

```
var eee = document.getElementById('elementId').style.top.replace("px", "");
var aaa = parseInt(eee, 10);
aaa = aaa - 300;

document.getElementById('elementId').style.top = aaa + `px`;
```